# Two Spring RequestContextFilter and @Component annotations

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, servlet-filters

I have two filter classes extending from  `org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter`, both configured in the `web.xml` in the same way, both using `@Component` annotation. When I had only one, everything worked correctly. When I added the second one, it didn't get registered.

Why? How can I solve this? I need the two filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Spring `@Component` is class based and not name based, the second filter doesn't load because it's being shadowed by the first one. The fact that the two implementation classes are different is irrelevant because Spring searches for something extending Filter.

The solution is to use a qualifier for each `@Component` (e.g. `@Component(value = "MyFilter1")` ) and to declare in the `web.xml` the name of the filter as the qualifier (e.g. `<filter><filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>...</filter>`.

Don't forget to use `org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy` and declare the filter mapping as well.

Yes - it's strange, but I'm answering my own question immediately. I started writing it after searching for a few hours and then had an idea. I tested it and it works - but there's no reason for someone else to search for a few hours again.

Comment: I am unclear on exactly the solution which you are suggesting. Would you please add some details, like the class definition for both of your subclasses, along with the relevant method signatures, also please include all the pertinent sections of your web.xml, and your application context, if applicable.